# Creating Several Wireless Access Points

Tags: wireless-access-point

I want to create several wireless access points. Initially, I used the `create_ap` script. However, it is when creating two access points on two awus adapters. On one access point there is Internet, on the other it is not. I create access points like this:

```
sudo ./create_ap --daemon -c 1 wlx00c0cad3c750 --mac 00:c0:ca:d3:c7:50 enp4s0 ap1 12345678
sudo ./create_ap --daemon -c 1 wlx00c0cad3c751 --mac 00:c0:ca:d3:c7:51 enp4s0 ap2 12345678
```

Are there any other ways to create access points?

Comment: I think only one access point per adapter

Comment: @Inee, yes, but I use several adapters

Comment: You can write your own script that calls the script `create_ap` multiple times.

Comment: @user68186, I call the create_ap script in the terminal twice, two access points are created. When connecting to the first access point, there is an Internet connection, but the second access point does not have an Internet connection.

Comment: This point is not clear in your question. It looks like you are asking about creating multiple AP. If you are asking about how to provide Internet access to both of all APs you have to edit your question and make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

you may use `hostapd` and dublicate config as well as startscript. the is a parameter inside the `hostapd.conf` file defining the interface  (e.g. interface=wlp1s0) to be used.
This requires separate PID files and possibly separate sockets.